# How to preload images?

Tags: css

I'm using a big Background image on hover which is set in css `background {....}`

It takes time to load first time upon mouse over so I want to preload this `background` image.

What is the best option to do this either using pure css or javascript or jquery?

Pls don't suggest me **CSS Sprite**.

Comment: @Josh Stodola - because in my case i can't make or edit image.

Comment: gear-solid: is the image dynamically loaded or is it always the same?

Comment: Pick your favorite [duplicate](http://www.google.com/search?q=preload+image+site:stackoverflow.com)!

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look to the [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) techniques which could decrease considerably your images size. By the way it'll help to preload all hover, or dynamically changing decorations images has they have been loaded at page loading.

Comment: How come you get 3 upvotes for the same answer, when I answered first? Anyway, apparently this doesn't work for him.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is always the same, the following will do it:

```
pic1= new Image(100,25);
pic1.src="http://someplace.com/image1.gif";
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a hover effect, use [css sprites](http://www.google.ca/search?q=css+sprites) and forget javascript. Easier, and fewer http requests.

Comment: in my case i cant use css spite

Answer (score 0):

Or don't preload it as such.

Have the image contain both states of the image, then use CSS to re-position the image to show the state that you desire.

If you have multiple images, it might be worth implementing a sprite as mentioned by someone else.

Another link: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/